# Install Sitecore 10 without admin access to SQL Server or user sa

Tags: installation

I want to install Sitecore but not having user admin user for SQL Server. Anyway of installing this with Windows authentication.

Comment: If you have windows authentication access with the ability to create a new admin user. With that, you can go ahead with installation with the newly created user.